# how to Authenticate WCF service globally using custom token

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, wcf-security

I wanted to add a global Custom token authentication on each service call in wcf rest service.
My service having more than 50 (Get/Post) methods.
Now I am passing token in each method and authenticate  them, Now i wanted to do that globally using something like global.asax or routing or attribute reading

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the dynamic solution i went through multiple links to understand WCF parameter validation and I found the solution here

> Create a class that inherate *IparameterInspector*
>
> IparameterInspector usesbase class as *IoperationBehaviour*
>
> Add the created class to your operation contract as a Attribute
>
> For detail descrption see the link
> *[WCF Extensibility using IParameterInspector](http://www.developerin.net/a/62-Code-Snippets/105-WCF-Extensibility-using-IParameterInspector)*

If you want you can Comment you query or question to get my actual code for Get and Post method